# Update Friends List ListView with Asmack

Tags: android, listview, asmack

I'm trying to Dynamically update a Friends list using the Asmack API.  For testing purposes I am using my Facebook account.  I found that if I login with my connection then use

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Roster people = connection.getRoster();

people.people.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

        public void presenceChanged(Presence arg0) {

          contacts.clear();

          for(RosterEntry entry: people.getEntries()) {

                if(people.getPresence(entry.getUser()).equals(Presence.Type.available)) {
                    Contact person = new Contact();
                    person.setJid(entry.getUser());
                    person.setName(entry.getName());

                    contacts.add(person);
                }
            }

           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

This doesn't seem to work. My listView still remains empty. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone curious the best way to do it was using an AsyncTask. To populate it initially and a RosterListener to keep it up to date. As real time changes occurred.

Here is my code. Hopefully it helps someone in the future.

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,getString(R.string.DialogConnecting1),getString(R.string.DialogConnecting2) + " " + settings.getString("username", "NOT SET") + ". " + getString(R.string.DialogConnecting3), true, true);

    new ContactFetcher().execute("");

}

class ContactFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        contacts.clear();

        while(connection.getRoster().getEntries().isEmpty()){}

        people = connection.getRoster();

        for(RosterEntry entry: people.getEntries()) {

            //if(people.getPresence(entry.getUser()).getType().equals(Presence.Type.available)) {
                Contact person = new Contact();
                person.setJid(entry.getUser());
                person.setName(entry.getName());
                person.setStatus(people.getPresence(entry.getUser()));
                //person.setMsgState("");

                contacts.add(person);
            //}

        }

        return "";
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter.sort(comparator);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        pd.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It is just a basic class with private members jid, name, status, as well as your standard getters and setters. I believe I also made it Parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a `RosterListener` to add, delete or update your friends. See the [doc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/RosterListener.html).